# Auto Collapse / Expand next to functions and procedures

Tags: delphi

In the editor, you have - and + buttons next to procedures and functions so you can hide / show them.  Like below
[image: Open]
[image: Closed]

Is there any way to add these next to say If statements or Case Statements ect.  Or is it only for procedures and functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those + (expand) and - (contract) marks can not be added for, as you asked, `if` or `case` statements per se. But you can manually add "foldable regions" anywhere in the code for the same effect.

Use

```
{$region 'a comment that will remain visible when region is contracted'}
 ... 
{$endregion}
```

around code you may want to fold/unfold